# Custom-created or personalized products with Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I’m building a webshop with Craft Commerce where customers will be able to customize/personalize parts of clothes based on a predefined set of options.

With a pullover for example, customers should be able to change material, color and prints of the body, sleeves and cuffs individually. The different options are individual products themselves and have their own stock information. So the product bought by the customer will be composed of several product variants for different parts of the pullover.

With Woo Commerce for example there is a Composite Products Plugin, that seems like a solution to this: https://woocommerce.com/products/composite-products/

Is there a similar plugin for Craft Commerce, that would help me with building this feature? Or is there another way of solving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a plugin for this, so the only way to solve this would be to build the plugin for this yourself, if you have the skills or resources for this. It could be solved by creating a purchasable with (optional) relations to all the products needed, checking the stock of those products on adding it to the basket, and/or on checkout.

What I would start with, though, is creating an issue on [Commerce's Github](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues), to see if others have a need for this and hope that Pixel & Tonic's crew will do it for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a plugin at all. Commerce provides the ability to add [custom options](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-docs/blob/eaa6649bb3a88f172d097a1d3a23d30bb5462f80/en/adding-to-and-updating-the-cart.md#line-item-options-and-notes) for each line item in your add to cart form.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! From my perspective it will be difficult managing stock for individual parts of clothes (i.e. sleeves) using custom options? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If you need to manage stock for each combination, sounds like you would want to create a variant for each combination, and you wouldn't need custom options.